# Sql server Intellisense is not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query, ssms, intellisense

My sql server management studio intellisense is not working, below is my SSMS version and screen shot that I have tried, my SQL server is not installed locally but I am accessing the sql server remotely, maybe a firewall issue?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

It works at will, sometimes work sometimes does not work

[image]

[image]

I have this blue icon on my database instance, it might be blocking it as it is some firewall issue

[image]

Comment: I am accessing the sql server instance remotly

Answer (score 3):

[Intellisense has always been a little buggy.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/troubleshooting-intellisense?view=sql-server-ver16)

Sometimes refreshing your intellisense cache fixes it, which you can accomplish with the shortcut of `Ctrl + Shift + R`. Sometimes you need to close the SQL worksheet and open a new one. Other times you unfortunately need to just restart SSMS completely.

Comment: Done all of the above no use

Comment: @kinnangiant Restarting the SSMS client completely doesn't work (even just temporarily)?

Comment: no not even temporarily, it might be firewall issue as i am seeing a blue icon on my database instance, it means that due to some firewall policy it shows a blue icon on the database https://i.stack.imgur.com/o8xFl.png

Comment: @kinnangiant I've never heard of the firewall affecting intellisense, but I guess anything is possible. If you directly login to the server hosting your SQL Server instance (e.g. via RDP) and run SSMS locally on it, does intellisense work? This would remove the factor of the firewall. And for that matter, does **anyone** else using your SQL Server experience this issue?...does **everyone** else experience it?

Comment: Does this make sense (image attached), how can SQL Search (3.6) Gets installed if i did not had the correct .Net version on my system. and if i recalled correctly it worked correctly once for me

https://imgur.com/a/QeMZJTC

Comment: @kinnangiant It's possible SQL Search was dependent on a lower version of the .NET Framework when you initially installed it, and a future update (even a minor revision update) to SQL Search required a newer version of the .NET Framework. If that's RedGate support, I'd follow their advice and also let them know you're curious if it could be a potential firewall issue too.

Comment: This is my .net framework version (4.8)
https://imgur.com/a/28jG5ZC
and this is my Sql Search Version (3.6)
https://imgur.com/a/KjCHavS

Comment: @kinnangiant Unfortunately there's nothing else we can offer as help here. Please work with RedGate Support.

Comment: I am in discussion with redgate on this, and it has not been closed yet, lets see what they have to say, as I am working with them and showing them but still it does not work on my system